# Mongoose update value in object nested in array in nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document like this:

```
{
  _id: "...",
  nested_document: {
    _id: "...",
    myObject: {
      fields: [
        { value: "VALUE_TO_CHANGE" },
        { value: "KEEP_THIS_ONE" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to update the `VALUE_TO_CHANGE` (by its index) with mongoose:

```
await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $set: {
        "nested_document.myObject.fields.$[0].value": value
      }
    },
    {},
    () => {}
  );
```

But nothing is being updated. Why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as the schema is not strict, I need to use this parameter in config of the update query and the query looks like this:

```
await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $set: {
        "nested_document.myObject.fields.0.value": value
      }
    },
    { strict: false },
    () => {}
  );
```